# How the change the height of a cxProgressBar

Tags: delphi, devexpress

How the change the height of a cxProgressBar?

I've tried this but no luck so far:

```
var
  cxProgressBar1: TcxProgressBar;
begin
  cxProgressBar1 := TcxProgressBar.Create(Self);

  with cxProgressBar1 do
  begin
    Parent := Self;
    Position := 22;
    Width := 113;
    Height := 120;
    Properties.Orientation := cxorVertical;
  end;
end;
```

The height remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to set AutoSize := false; before setting Width and/or Height

So this is the solution :

```
var
  cxProgressBar1: TcxProgressBar;
begin
  cxProgressBar1 := TcxProgressBar.Create(Self);

  with cxProgressBar1 do
  begin
    AutoSize := false;
     .....
  end;
end;
```